# Edit data from blog in Iframe

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I'm currently building a blog from scratch and I'm using php, javascript + Iframe to add new posts to the blog, and this works perfect. The problem I'm having is my "Edit post" function. When I'm editing a post it should fetch the posted text, and it sort of does. However it's got a Not found header, and 404 error message along with the text from the blog post.
This is the code I'm using for editing:

```
<iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" style="border:#000000 1px solid; width:700px; height:300px;" src="<?php echo $row_getPost['blog_entry']; ?>"></iframe>
```

I've tried to put the Iframe into the php tags like this, but it didn't work:

```
<?php echo <iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" style="border:#000000 1px solid; width:700px; height:300px;" src="$row_getPost['blog_entry']; "></iframe>?>
```

Is there any way to do this Edit post function with Iframe, or should I just do it with a textarea tag? I did that before, and it works. The reason I'm using Iframe and Javascript is to use javascript functions like change text appearance, inserting links, images and more.

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: What is `$row_getPost['blog_entry'];`? Is it an URL to the post content? IFrame needs to have URL as its src parameter, so passing content text won't work. Are you sure you don't need a simple `div` here?

Comment: @sebapalus Hi! blog_entry points to a table in my database, and $row_getPost is the function that gets the data from that table based on the posts ID.

Comment: so, as I wrote before, `src` can't be a text, it needs to be an URL

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for an "iframe" at least I can't find any reason to use it with your features.
In your second try to call an iframe with php echo you forgot the quotation marks and the semicolon at the end:

```
<?php echo '<iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" style="border:#000000 1px solid; width:700px; height:300px;" src="' . $row_getPost["blog_entry"] . '"></iframe>'; ?>
```

You can solve everything you want without that iframe when you want to avoid a reload of the browser javascript will be your friend.
I would suggest that you try it with jQuery or AngularJS.
These two will do the most for you to help you to write less code.

**Edit:**
Didn't see that answer top. sebapalus is right, you have to use an URL for the "src" attribute. An iframe is an embedded file/site.
You can read more about the attributes of an iframe here:

[HTML  Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

Comment: I got a "Syntax error" message when I put the iframe into the php tags.  Perhaps it's best to ditch the iframe and see if I can get the "edit posts" function to work with jQuery. Just learning php and sql, so I'm trying out different guides to build this blog thing. Thanks for your answer, Tipo and sebapalus!

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake with the "src" attribute. I changed the post. Now it works.
But you will have more fun when you "ditch" the iframe. ^^
There are so much more possibilities to do it with PHP or JavaScript.
Keep on trying and learning and don't hesitate to ask here. ;-)